# 'Do nothing' operator in Oz

Tags: oz

As a part of a learning course, i was making a procedure that took lists as parameters and then operated on their contents. It went like this:

```
proc {myProc A B}
    case B of H|T then
        %do something
        {myProc A T}
    end
end
```

However, when i have tried executing it, i encountered failures when `B` is an ampty list (that is, `nil`). Why is that?

What should i do in order to do nothing if `B` is nil? As far as i know, adding empty `else` clause will result in compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a case for nil:

```
proc {myProc A B}
  case B
  of H|T then
    %do something
    {myProc A T}
  [] nil then
    skip
  end
end
```